# Why are flow interviews paused

Tags: visual-workflow, flow-interviews

I created some flows which get triggered at certain conditions (on opportunity won send survey, send email, ...). Now I am seeing some of them in a list of Paused Flow Interviews. Details page is not very helpful, because the Pause Reason is empty for all of them. The number of this flows is relatively small, around 5 per day max.

Why did they pause at all? I also can't resume them (or something), but just delete them.

I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: Are these flows with scheduled actions?

Comment: I am investigating the same thing here. So far it looks that when exception occurs, it's pausing the interview. Have you found out anything else yet?